# moving field to a new column if it contains value in a certain column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

```
LINE    TXOBJECT    TXNAME  TXID    LANG TXLINES
1       KNMT         1234   0001     EN
2         *          MEA
2         *          MEB
2         *          MEB
1       KNMT        12345   0001     EN
2         *          MEN
2         *          MED
2         *          MEC
1       KNMT        123456  0001     EN
2         *          LADY
2         *          BOY
2         *          DUDE
```

I have a file that i got and i needed some fields in a new column so i was able to put the fields that i want in a new row, but i wasn't able to put the TXNAME column on LINE 2 into the TXLINES column.

I don't know if my explanation on what i want is right but i will explain what i need below

I want this below.

```
LINE    TXOBJECT    TXNAME  TXID    LANG TXLINES
1       KNMT         1234   0001     EN  MEA MEB MEB
1       KNMT        12345   0001     EN  MEN MED MEC
1       KNMT        123456  0001     EN  LADY BOY DUDE
```

Please advise on the best possible ways to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
g = df.groupby((df.LINE == 1).cumsum())
txl = g['TXNAME'].apply(lambda x: x[1:].values).values
df = g.head(1).assign(TXLINES=txl).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = '''\
LINE    TXOBJECT    TXNAME  TXID    LANG TXLINES
1       KNMT         1234   0001     EN
2         *          MEA
2         *          MEB
2         *          MEB
1       KNMT        12345   0001     EN
2         *          MEN
2         *          MED
2         *          MEC
1       KNMT        123456  0001     EN
2         *          LADY
2         *          BOY
2         *          DUDE'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+').fillna('')

# Restructure
g = df.groupby((df.LINE == 1).cumsum())
txl = g['TXNAME'].apply(lambda x: x[1:].values).values
df = g.head(1).assign(TXLINES=txl).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   LINE TXOBJECT  TXNAME TXID LANG            TXLINES
0     1     KNMT    1234    1   EN    [MEA, MEB, MEB]
1     1     KNMT   12345    1   EN    [MEN, MED, MEC]
2     1     KNMT  123456    1   EN  [LADY, BOY, DUDE]
```

---

**Explanation**:

The aim here is to catch all the lines that are `TXOBJECT == "*"` and one way to do that would be to use the fact we got a LINE column. By picking out the lines with value `1` and apply cumsum() we can get the lines grouped. From here we do twp operations: get the txlines values and we take the first line of each group and restructure your data.

And by using `txl = g['TXNAME'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[1:])).values` instead you get:

```
   LINE TXOBJECT  TXNAME TXID LANG        TXLINES
0     1     KNMT    1234    1   EN    MEA MEB MEB
1     1     KNMT   12345    1   EN    MEN MED MEC
2     1     KNMT  123456    1   EN  LADY BOY DUDE
```

You could also change the txl = to, if that is more clear:

```
txl = g['TXNAME'].apply(list).str[1:].values
```